# Spring Roo v1.1.5 with Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-roo

I'm trying to use Spring Roo with Intellj IDEA 12 and Jdk 7. I set the Roo Home path in the Roo Tool Configuration window to the Spring Roo 1.1.5 folder. Now when I start the Roo Console, I get a bunch of error messages.

**Snippet of the error messages**

> ERROR: Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.backup-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.backup [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor.event)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 39.0: missing requirement [39.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.ant)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]])
>   ERROR: Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 36.0: missing requirement [36.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 39.0: missing requirement [39.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.ant)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]])
>   ERROR: Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.creator-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.creator [9]: Unable to resolve 9.0: missing requirement [9.0] package; (package=javax.xml.parsers))
>   ERROR: Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.dbre-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.dbre [10]: Unable to resolve 10.0: missing requirement [10.0] package; (package=javax.xml.parsers))

I am not sure what is causing this error. I haven't tried it with a different jdk yet. Any Intellij Spring-Roo users who have faced a similar issue?

Comment: last time I tried roo(couple of months ago)it didn't work with jdk 7. I found the integration with intellij not so good, went back to sts for roo development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the version of Felix packed with Roo is incompatible with Java 7.  This worked for me.

In the $ROO_HOME/bin, replace org.apache.felix.framework-3.x.x.jar with a newer version of Felix.  I used org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar.

I downloaded Felix from here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/felix/

There is no need to change the name of the jar.  The roo.sh script loads all the jars in the directory into the classpath.  So, you must remove the old version (and possibly back it up somewhere).